# Array of 1-dimensional array and array row yields different results

Tags: numpy

I am having difficulty to understand why neither B or C equals A. How can I extract a specific row from f and calculate the same result as in `A`?

```
import numpy as np

L = np.array([
    [2.66667,1.33333],
    [0.8,1.6]
    ])

f = np.array([[0.5,0.333333]])

A = L*f.T

B = L*f[0,:]
C = L*f[0,:].T

print(20*'*')
print(A)
print(20*'*')
print(B)
print(20*'*')
print(C)
print(20*'*')
```

Output:

```
********************
[[1.333335  0.666665 ]
 [0.2666664 0.5333328]]
********************
[[1.333335   0.44444289]
 [0.4        0.5333328 ]]
********************
[[1.333335   0.44444289]
 [0.4        0.5333328 ]]
********************
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L = np.array([
    [2.66667,1.33333],
    [0.8,1.6]
    ])

f = np.array([[0.5,0.333333]])
```

`L` is (2,2), `f` is (1,2).  `f.T` is (2,1)

```
A = L*f.T
```

This broadcasts the (2,2) with (2,1), replicating the the `f.T` columns to (2,2).

```
B = L*f[0,:]
C = L*f[0,:].T
```

`f[0,:]` is (2,) shape, 1d. `f[0,:].T` is the same because there's only one 1 axis to switch.

Here (2,2) times (2,) => (2,2) times (1,2), That's the same as `L*f`.

In `A` you are multiplying the columns of `L` by `f`:

```
In [235]: L[0,:]*f[0,:]
Out[235]: array([1.333335  , 0.44444289])
```

In `B` it's the rows of `L`:

```
In [236]: L[:,0]*f[0,:]
Out[236]: array([1.333335 , 0.2666664])
```

The mix and match of rows and columns could be clearer with `L` was (2,3) shaped.

### edit

```
In [34]: np.array([L[:,i]*f[0] for i in range(2)]).T
Out[34]: 
array([[1.333335 , 0.666665 ],
       [0.2666664, 0.5333328]])
In [35]: np.array([L[i,:]*f[0] for i in range(2)])
Out[35]: 
array([[1.333335  , 0.44444289],
       [0.4       , 0.5333328 ]])
```

I got [235] and [236] switched.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! This means I can calculate the result for `A` stepwise by `L[:,0]*f[0,:]` and `L[:,1]*f[0,:]` ... possibly in a loop and then cocatenating the arrays? Is it possible to extract the first row from `f` and calculate the same result as in `A` in one line? It works with `(MRIO_L.T*MRIO_f[0,:]).T` which seems a bit over-engineered (I should better say *trial and errored*).

Comment: I added the iterative equivalents.  I use `f[0]` because the we don't need to 'transpose' it.  Looks like I mixed up rows and columns in the earlier example.